# Stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Determine the stochastic dynamic of such process: (Sin(Z(t)), {Z(t), t > 0} B.M. of dim 1.

Is it a Martingale? Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It greatly benefits everybody here if you provide your attempt at a solution so people here may see your work and more appropriately provide you with an answer rather than *handing you a solution for free*.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$d(sin(Z(t))=cos(Z(t))dZ(t)-\dfrac{1}{2}sin(Z(t))dt$$